# Can I draw arrows between two minipages?

Tags: arrows, minipage

I have an exam where my students should connect two objects in different columns on a page. The two columns are one with text alternatives and one with pictures/formulae. 
I want to draw a red line connecting the correct object for the corrected sheet, how can I do it?

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
{\bf A} \\ \vspace{10 mm}
(1) Surjektivitet \\ \vspace{20 mm}
(2) Reflexivitet \\ \vspace{20 mm}
(3) Symmetri  \\ \vspace{20 mm}
(4) Injektivitet \\  \vspace{20 mm}
(5) Transitivitet \\ \vspace{30 mm}

Lycka till!
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
{\bf B}  \\ \vspace{10 mm}
(a)\\ 
\begin{center}
\vspace{-10 mm} \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Injection} \\  \vspace{20 mm}
\end{center}
\stepcounter{footnote}
(b) \textbf{$\forall a \in A, \;\; a\mathcal{R}a$ }. \footnote{  $\forall a \in A$, läses ut som för varje element $a$ i mängden $A$ så gäller\dots}\\ \vspace{20 mm}

(c) \textbf{$\forall x,y,z \in X,$ $(x\mathcal{R}y \wedge y\mathcal{R}z  \Rightarrow x\mathcal{R}z)$ }\\ \vspace{20 mm}

(d)\\   \begin{center}  
\vspace{-10 mm} \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Surjection}\\    \end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

Ex. (3) connects to (b) with a red arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `\tikzmark`. First you place some marks and then use the `\Connect` command to connect the appropriate marks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node (#1) {};%
}

\newcommand\Connect[3][]{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[->,red,>=latex,#1] (#2.north east) -- ( $ (#3.north west) + (-20pt,0) $ );%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
{\bfseries A}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),itemsep=20mm]
\item Surjektivitet\tikzmark{starta}
\item Reflexivitet\tikzmark{startb}
\item Symmetri\tikzmark{startc}
\item Injektivitet\tikzmark{startd}
\item Transitivitet\tikzmark{starte}
\end{enumerate}
Lycka till!
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
{\bfseries B}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),itemsep=20mm]
\item\tikzmark{enda}  
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,height=1cm]{Injection}
\end{center}
%\stepcounter{footnote}
\item\tikzmark{endb} $\forall a \in A, \;\; a\mathcal{R}a$.\footnote{$\forall a \in A$, läses ut som för varje element $a$ i mängden $A$ så gäller\dots}
\item\tikzmark{endc} $\forall x,y,z \in X,$ $(x\mathcal{R}y \wedge y\mathcal{R}z  \Rightarrow x\mathcal{R}z)$
\item\tikzmark{endd}
\begin{center}  
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth,height=1cm]{Surjection} 
\end{center}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\Connect{startb}{endb}
\Connect{starte}{endc}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document. I also changed the height of the included images, just for the example code.

Not related to the question, but you were using a lot of manual adjustments that are not really necessary (and, in some case, are not correct); in particular, I used the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to customize some enumerate environments, allowing you to minimize the manual interventions.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is greatly appreciated. Will consider the other improvements too.